# textbox should not allow html data using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<input type="text" id="NotesReturn" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#NotesReturn").keypress(function (e) {
         kCode = e.keyCode || e.charCode
         var htmlRegExp=new RegExp("/<(\w+)((?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(??:'[^']*')|(?:'[^']*')|[^>\s]+))?)*)\s*(\/?)>/");
         if (htmlRegExp.test(kCode) || $(this).val().length >= 512)
            e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#NotesReturn").bind('paste', function(e){
         var pastedValue=this.value+window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
         var trimmedValue=pastedValue.substring(0, 512);
         var htmlRegExp = new RegExp("/<(\w+)((?:\s+\w+(?:\s*=\s*(??:'[^']*')|(?:'[^']*')|[^>\s]+))?)*)\s*(\/?)>/");
         if(!htmlRegExp.test(trimmedValue))
         {
             $(this).val(null);
             $(this).val(trimmedValue.toString());
         }
         e.preventDefault();
    });

</script>
```

My textbox should not allow html data.But it is throwing unexpected quantifier error.can someone help me.I could not figure out the error.

Comment: The parentheses in your regexp aren't balanced. And you shouldn't put `/` at the beginning and end when you use `new RegExp()`, you only do that when writing the regex as a literal.

Comment: I don't get "unexpected quantifier". Chrome complains "Invalid group".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unexpected quantifier error is due to the `??` in `(??:` which should probably be simply `(?:` to indicate a non-capturing group.
As Barmer stated, the opening and closing forward slashes should not be included and the round brackets are unbalanced. You need to remove a right round bracket or add another left one.
You also need to escape the backslashes by preceding them with a backslash when using the RegExp constructor.
Doing the above will give you a valid regex but whether it will work correctly to disallow html is another question.